# How to change path for output images in webpack 5?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have some pictures in folder "src/assets/img/". I would like to keep the relative path to pictures.
Example: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1skF.png) -> [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnrGW.png)

Part of my webpack config:

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name][ext]',
    clean: true,
  },

  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          options: {
            disable: !isProduction,
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
              quality: 80,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 3,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: [0.7, 0.9],
              speed: 4,
            },
          },
        },
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/img/[name][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
};
```

But all folders inside are deleting -> [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqic9.png)
I'm sure it's about

```
generator: { 
  filename: 'assets/img/[name][ext]' 
}
```

But I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

To set the path for different types of assets (for fonts, etc.), you need to add the `'asset/resource'` type to the rules. And in the output add the `assetModuleFilename` field with the function. In this case, all assets will be saved to the same path as in the `src` folder:

```js
// File: webpack.config.js

const config = {
  ...
  output: {
    ...
    assetModuleFilename: pathData => {
        const filepath = path.dirname(pathData.filename).split('/').slice(1).join('/');
        return `${filepath}/[name][ext]`;
    },
  },
  module: {
    ...
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp|avif|ico)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you and others.

```js
generator: {
  filename: ({ filename }) => {
    if (filename.includes('source')) {
      return filename.replace('source', 'dist');
    }
    if (filename.includes('node_modules')) {
      return filename.replace('node_modules', 'dist');
    }
    return filename;
  },
},
```